# Calculated field syntax error

Tags: calculated-column

I'm trying to get the difference of two date fields in terms of years. SP keeps giving syntax error. Any pointers where I'm wrong?

```
=DATE(YEAR([Awarded Project End Date])-YEAR([Awarded Project Start Date]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning a date then you need to pass a YEAR, MONTH and DAY.  Right now you are subtracting two years and trying to return the result as a date which is not valid.  Try something like this:

```
=YEAR([Awarded Project End Date])-YEAR([Awarded Project Start Date])
```

Comment: This worked. I needed this to define number of fields to be shown using jquery

Answer (score 1):

Year() returns an integer and you cannot convert that into a DATE().  Try this instead :

```
=DATEDIF([Awarded Project End Date], [Awarded Project Start Date],"y")
```

There is more info available [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx).

Comment: I used this formula before, I was passing the answer as a number. Good to know. Thanks!